# Copying a folder into multiple folders

Tags: batch-file

I have a folder with some content which I want to copy into 260 folders.

I guess this is doable with a bat-file and a for-loop, but I can't seem to understand how to do it. Anyone keen to help? :)

Comment: how do you have the other folders listed? do we have to find them, or do you have a list of the folders?

Comment: it is all folders inside another folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me.

```
FOR /D %%a in ("dst\*") do 
   xcopy "src\*.*"  "%%a" /s /i /c /y
```

Answer (score 0):

this will copy a file into every sub folder, 1 level down, so it will copy into `dir1` but not into `dir1\subdir`

`for /f "delims=" %a in ('dir /ad /b') do copy filename.ext "%a"`

if you need it in every folder, from the directory you type this in down throughout the whole diredctory structure, add `/s` to the `dir` command: `'dir /s /ad /b'`. this will get `dir1`, `dir1\subdir` and even `dir1\subdir\a\a\a\a\a\a`